# How to pass a keyboard input type as a parameter in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to pass an input type as a parameter to a textfield and I am not sure how to do this. I have tried this:

```
Widget textFieldBuilder(TextInputType inputType, String placeholder) {
   return Padding ( padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
    child: SizedBox(
     width: 300,
     child: TextField(
       keyboardType: inputType,
       decoration: InputDecoration(
       labelText: "$placeholder",
         border: OutlineInputBorder(
         borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
      ),
      filled: true,
      fillColor: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
  ),
 );
}
```

I thought the above mentioned way should work, but I guess the problem is calling the function, how should I pass this type of parameter?

I have tried this:

```
textFieldBuilder(TextInputType.emailAddress, "exemple@email.com"),
```

Comment: Does passing TextInputType.emailAddress not work? Does it give an error or does it just ignore it? Does it work if you write it directly?

Comment: It just ignores

Answer (score 0):

Just Try using this

```
final TextInputType keyboardType;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).